# Pronunciation/tones for hug (擁抱): yong1 bao4 or yong3 bao4?

Tags: pronunciation, tones

[CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/4056/) and [yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/sentsearch.php?word=%E6%93%81%E6%8A%B1) say the pronunciation for 擁抱 is yong1 bao4.

However, Google Translate and other pages say it's yong3 bao4.

What's the right pronunciation?

Comment: Sorry I can't see the difference... Both yong3 bao4?

Comment: Have you ever checked your question after you post it?

Comment: Supplementary information: [百度词典(yong1 bao4)](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%8B%A5%E6%8A%B1/2650).

Comment: yong3bao4 reminds me of 志玲姐姐,  给你一个大大的yong3bao4. lmao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Liang'an (兩岸)](https://www.moedict.tw/~%E6%93%81%E6%8A%B1) gives the Taiwanese Mandarin (國語) pronunciation as:

> yǒngbào

`yong3 bao4`

while noting the mainland Mandarin (普通话) pronunciation as being:

> yōngbào

`yong1 bao4`

Unless you're planning on speaking Taiwanese Mandarin, I'd stick with `yōng` `yong1`.

Answer (score 3):

Looking up the 1992 version of the [新华字典](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinhua_Zidian) published by the [商务印书馆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Press), on page 560 we find:

> **拥**<sub>（擁）</sub> yōng ㄩㄥ ❶抱（(连)—抱）。 [...the rest abbreviated]

Along with no other pronunciation available.

This, however, doesn't really explain why Google translate writes the pronunciation as yong3 bao4.  If you click on the "read" icon, Google still pronounces it as yong1 bao4. Probably a mistake on Google's part.

Comment: In mainland, it's always 拥 yōng 抱. But I heard some folks from TWN said yong3 bao4. I still remember 庾澄庆 a famous singer from TWN said yong3 bao4 in the very famous show, Voice of China(中国新歌声). ：）

Comment: @dan That is refreshing to know.  I do think your explanation could be a standalone answer if you provided more instances of yong3 bao4 because it addresses the question.